# Can a cross-reference data stream be achieved using Code in Zapier. Especifically to generate rows in GSheets from 2 different data streams?

Tags: zapier, basecamp

My goal is to create automatic to-do's in several projects in Basecamp 3 on a weekly basis.

To do this, I am using the Schedule app in Zapier which triggers the creation of several rows on a google spreadsheet. These rows then trigger the creation of to-do's in specific projects in Basecamp 3. The input of this rows, should be: project's name (used for the search step), to-do text.

I am using the Formatter App in Zapier to try and achieve this. On a first Formatter action, I am splitting the text using commas of all of the names of our projects and returning all the segments. On a second Formatter, I am splitting the text of all the to-do's text and, again, returning all the segments.

Formatter 1 Input (Projects): AA,BB,CC,DD

Formatter 2 Input (To-Do's Text): buy it, use it, break it, fix it

Now, the goal I am trying to achieve is illustrated in the attached diagram. Also illustrated is what the zap (as it is) is achieving with the data. [Data Stream Diagrams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe3rf.jpg)

We work often with Grasshopper, a Rhino 3D plug-in used for parametric modeling and data-drive design. In grasshopper this would be called a "cross-referenced" data-stream. Is this possible to achieve using Code in Zapier? If so, can I get a little help?

Thanks!

Zapier Zap GIF: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B85_sQemABgmQVd6MENRd0NsNGc

Answer (score 0):

I don't have permission to view your Google drive link, but I think I get the gist of what you're trying to do.

Rather than use Formatter, you're probably better off using Python as you'll have more control over what's getting returned. You can use Python's `itertools.product` to get every combination of your two lists.

```
# zapier runs in a vanilla python environment
# so you can import standard packages
import itertools 

letters = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']
actions = ['buy it', 'use it', 'break it', 'fix it']

combos = list(itertools.product(letters, actions)) 
# [('AA', 'buy it'), ('AA', 'use it'), ... ('DD', 'fix it')]
```

From there, you'll want to format that list as your action step expects (probably via a list comprehension such as `[{'code': c[0], 'action': c[1]} for c in combos]` and return the list from the code step.

A hidden feature of Zapier is that if an array is returned from a code step, the zap will run the action for each array element. Be careful though, that means for each input to the zap, the output will be run 16x (which can quickly eat into your task limit).

Hopefully that sets you on the right track. Let me know if somethings was unclear!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'm sorry, I got a notification. I made it public already. 

I'm sorry @xavdiv, I've never programmed in Python. I think I understand the logic in the idea but would you care to explain a bit more how could I achieve this in Zapier? I'm not sure of what sould go in the Input Data section of the zap. And, how can I format this list? Should that be done in the same Code step?

Thanks again!

Comment: Should the code look something like this? 

`import itertools 


letters = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']

actions = ['buy it', 'use it', 'break it', 'fix it']


combo = list(itertools.product(letters, actions)) 


return = list`

Comment: yep! you can put that into a python code step (so there'll be a trigger, code, and google sheets) and the sheets action will run 16 times every week. Make sure this fits within your task usage!